# Handle http fired by Flex in C# server

Tags: c#, apache-flex, http

Hi I am trying to send a simple HTTP message from Flex to C# server, but it seems that I am getting tow calls, first is the real one and the second is an empty one.

Why is that and how can I handle it?

This is my C# code:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 9400);
listener.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Server started");
Socket client;
while (true)
{
    client = listener.AcceptSocket();
    // client.Available is an expensive call so it's just for testing
    Console.WriteLine("Client accepted " + client.Connected + " " + client.Available);
    SocketHandler handler = new SocketHandler();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(handler.handleSocket, client);
}
```

this is the SocketHandler:

```
public void handleSocket(object socketObjeck)
{
    try
    {
        socket = (Socket)socketObjeck;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        SocketSettings.setSocket(socket);
        //blocker...
        try
        {
            socket.Receive(buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error\nFaild reading from socket\n" + e.Message);
            socket.Close();
            return;
        }
        parseData(buffer);

        socket.Close(3);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error\nError \n" + e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

And this is my flex code:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
request.data = "Hello from flex";
request.url = URL;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
loader.load(request);
```

I am always getting 2 calls.
The line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Client accepted " + client.Connected + " " + client.Available);
```

called twice.
What am I missing?

**Edit 1:**
I can tell you for sure that the second call is empty, it's not even seen in chrome JavaScript console, it's like flex opening a connection, and waiting for some response or I don't know what... but it sending no data.

**Edit 2:**

I been trying to send a true HTTP response a notice another thing, the second call is coming without waiting for the first call, if I am putting the response thread to short sleep(100 milliseconds in my test) then I am getting the second call before I been able to response for the first one.

P.S
Using Flex 4.6, Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Why not have a look at the client end at what is actually being requested? Firebug, Fiddler or Charles will all be able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all it turn around that it were the crossdomain request. If you do not adding a crossdomain file in you www folder, flex will send you an empty message(if you will try to response this message with crossdomain, it want work).

Answer (score 3):

As @Spender mentioned, it' difficult to know what the reason for the calls is, without knowing what the calls are.

However, given that you're using a `URLRequest` to communicate, it's possible that the first call is a request for the `crossdomain.xml` file, which must be present in order for the flash player to communicate with your server.

Other protocols have different initialisation calls (eg., `RemoteObject` or `NetConnection` will send an intial call to setup the local FlexClientId, and a `SocketServer` will call for a crossdomain.xml on a specific port.)

The moral of the story : You need to check what the content is of the request before you can respond.

Comment: +1 That's pretty much where I thought further investigation might lead (i.e. requests to crossdomain.xml)

Answer (score 1):

I see two points:

- [`crossdomain.xml`](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) has to be present [server-side](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html) for this to work from the client-side
- use [`HttpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) on the server-side instead `TcpListener`, it will make your code much more robust since it has all the http protocol details implemented and allows you to concentrate on just the "real work"

Please ask if you need further details/samples etc.

Comment: Indeed HttpListener solves the problem, but then you can't debug it because it require admin permission to run the server, and there is some extra parsing from Microsoft implementation that are a time wast and not necessary for me. And the most important , I can't know if this fix the problem, perhaps they just have a try catch on empty messages so I wan't even see it... About crossDomain, if that was the esiu then my client wouldn't be able to work at all, but it is, he is just sending unnecessary messages...

Comment: @Babibu `HttpListener` can be started without admin priviliges (esp. when you run it on port > 1023 like in your case 9400). You can use `netsh` with admin priviliges to register the base-URI and after this your application/HttpListener can run without admin priviliges...

Comment: @Babibu `HttpListener` uses the same OS components as IIS does (a kernel-module called HTTP.SYS)... it does not "swallow" empty messages

Comment: @Babibu I suspect that the "empty message" you see is due to the nature of http and your TcpListener-based approach not implementing fully/correctly the HTTP RFC...

Comment: I have all the reasons to believe that HttpListener, does some how swallow those messages, because it's a client bug. It doe's not happened when I am trying to reach the server from browser. But it's not really matters, because i am trying to make this work with the TcpListener, I can't find any reason why TcpListener wouldn't be able to handle it. TcpListener is the solution that I am looking for. Tnx for the netsh tip!

Comment: @Babibu Sorry, but I really don't believe that `HttpListener` is swallowing anything... To make that work with TcpListener you will need implement the HTTP RFC fully which from what I can see you did not - so you can't really tell whether it is an empty message or something happening because of your incomplete implementation of the http protocol on the server-side...

Comment: O.K fine, i am going to listen to you, and test it up. Can you help me with the HTTP headers that I need to send back? Can you give me the exact string that I should send to the client? I tell what it do...

Comment: @Babibu I can't tell you what exactly to send back since I don't know what the real goal ist - http is a complex protocol, the main source on what to support/send etc. is the [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html). You would not need to bother with that if you use `HttpListener`...

Comment: @Babibu Have you checked the RFC link in my last comment ?

Comment: yeah I been reading this one: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5, but more and more it seems to me like adobe bug... So I don't know...